# Interrupt car radio android bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech, voip, android-audiomanager

We're trying to play audio alerts from our android app (traffic information) over bluetooth connected car stereos. If we switch the car stereo audio input to bluetooth, the app audio plays. If it is on any other source, the app audio does not play, either from the stereo or from the device.

What we want to do, is to allow users to keep the stereo audio input on DAB/FM radio or other source, but have our app audio interrupt at certain times and play these traffic information alerts, like how `VOIP` apps manage to do (such as Facebook messenger), and the built-in telephony phone call app manages to do.

Here is the code we are using at the moment :

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.robbresearch.ttsandroidtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button speakNowButton;
    private TextView textView;
    TTSManager ttsManager = null;
    AudioManager am;

    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener =
        new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
                    // Pause playback
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                    // Resume playback
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                    //am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
                    am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);
                    // Stop playback
                }
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();

        ttsManager = new TTSManager();
        ttsManager.init(this);

        am = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Request audio focus for playback
        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                // Use the music stream.
                AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                // Request permanent focus.
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            //am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
            // Start playback.
        }

        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(
                android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
        speakNowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speak_now);
        speakNowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String text = textView.getText().toString();
                ttsManager.initQueue(text);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Releases the resources used by the TextToSpeech engine.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ttsManager.shutDown();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/speak_now"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Speak Now" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**We have these additional permissions in android manifest :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

We would greatly appreciate any advice on how to achieve this, thanks :)

We only need to support newer versions of android if necessary.

Comment: Does 'audio ducking' work http://stackoverflow.com/a/36925768/1256219

Comment: I've tried requesting audio focus with AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK and that made no difference - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following code :

```
audioM.setMode(audioM.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioM.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioM.startBluetoothSco();
audioM.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

And the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

There was no need to set thread priority or request audio focus.

Note that I'm currently getting a 15 second delay between calling TextToSpeech.speak() and hearing the audio over the car radio. When I've solved that I'll update this answer.

Comment: Good to know this.. The delay seems to be a common problem... You may find some solution stackoverflow itself regarding this..

Comment: well it is probably obvious to everyone else, but it took me some time to realize that I had also to close everything again with am.stopBluetoothSco(); (quite easy) and  am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); (this one took me quite a while..)

Answer (score 1):

To reach to any solution for your problem, we must understand first what facility does car audio system provides with bluetooth.

Car audio system support A2DP profile along with HandsFree profile for attaining calls. Now, when bluetooth is selected as the source anything which is played by your app on A2DP profile will be played by audio system. However, once you've switched to other source like radio, even though your device is connected with A2DP profile with car audio system nothing will be played which you are facing now. However, few things that can be tried here, which interrupts the radio play as well are:

1. We know that when any call comes, we get alert with phone number even when we are listening to radio. This alert portion you can use for your solution. However, I dont know much if we can send phone ring alert from app. These alerts are at lower level just AT commands. Some search would be needed to check this.
2. In some car audio system, there is facility that when sms comes it alerts you. This alert part can also be explored.

I could see these two option which could help you. But this is not the only option I guess. Please try to find car audio systems bluetooth spec sheet. There you could know what other bluetooth alert features they provide.

I will update this answer I find any hint on my above suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: I've requested the bluetooth audio spec for the stereo of the model I'm using for testing (Jaguar XF), I'll see if I work anything out from that.